# Symfony2 - Accessing user-defined functions from a Command

Tags: php, symfony, console, command

As a console command only allows for the `config()` and `execute()` functions to be declared, how can I declare user-defined functions and call them?

Comment: Please speficy more what do you want? As executing from the console only `execute()` is called.

Comment: You can declare any methods you like and call them from execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define and call any function in your Command class:

```
<?php

namespace ...\Command;

use ...

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
       // ...

       $this->mySuperFunction();
    }

    protected function mySuperFunction()
    {
      // your code goes here...
    }
}
```

If you want to output something, then pass your output object to your function

```
$this->mySuperFunction($output);
```

and use it:

```
protected function mySuperFunction(OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->write('hello world!');
}
```